# Postgres: ERROR: value too long for type character(4)

Tags: postgresql, function

I'm new to Postgres and currently trying to write a function that takes in an integer and then calls another (definitely working) pre-written function with that input. If I call the pre-written function directly, e.g.:

```
select * from func(3456789);
```

I get the result I expect, with no errors. However, if I call it inside my function:

```
create or replace function my_func(_id integer)
    returns setof Record
as $$
declare
    rec Record;
begin
    for rec in
        select * from func(_id)
    loop
        return next rec;
    end loop; 

end;
$$ language plpgsql
;
```

where I call it with exactly the same parameter:

```
select * from my_func(3456789);
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  value too long for type character(4)
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function my_func(integer) line 5 at FOR over SELECT rows
```

Why are these two cases different, and how can I fix it?

EDIT:

func(_sid) returns this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION func(_sid integer) RETURNS SETOF Record
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$ ...
```

and Record is defines like this:

```
create type Record as (code char(8), name char(4), num integer, work char(4));
```

Comment: The names in your question don't seem to match.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Yep, sorry, I changed the names so it would be easier to read, but I missed one.

Comment: Isn't it the `transcript(_id)` function that's raising the exception?

Comment: @eurotrash Yes you're right. Sorry, transcript(_id) is func(_id). I renamed it to make the question simpler, but missed that one.

Comment: Is that really all that `my_func` does? Do you have an overload of it that's being called instead?

Comment: That is really all `my_func` does. I haven't had the chance to make it do more yet, since making it do this doesn't even work. As I was writing this post, It struck me that it might have something to do with `Record`? `func` returns a set or `Record`s, is it okay that `my_func` does the same, but one at a time in the loop?

Comment: What is the definition of the type that `func` returns? Try this: say `func` returns (INTEGER, TEXT), change your query instead to `select * from my_func(3456789) AS x(a INTEGER, b TEXT)` but with the proper `func` data types of course.

Comment: I've updated the question to include the function def. Thanks for the advice, I'll try it out now.

Comment: Oh you've actually defined a type called Record? That's suuuch a bad idea, since postgres already has a RECORD type. If it's actually `Record`, put the name in quotes wherever it's used. Try making that change . Unless you didn't put it in quotes when creating it...

Comment: Oh, luckily not. It's actually called NewTranscriptRecord, I'd just shortened it for the question and didn't realise postgres already defines RECORD. Ironically, when I tried your earlier suggestion I got the error `a column definition list is only allowed for functions returning "record"`

Comment: Yeah that's why I suggested that cause i thought you were actually returning PG's record type.

Answer (score 0):

Every line that is returned by your function `func` is mapped to a Record.
So the error you are getting says that one of the lines in the function result contains at column positions of `name` and/or `work` a value bigger than the one required by the columns (wich is 4).